# PHP ZipArchive is not adding any files (Windows)

Tags: php, windows, php-ziparchive

I'm failing to put even a single file into a new zip archive.

makeZipTest.php:

```
<?php

$destination = __DIR__.'/makeZipTest.zip';
$fileToZip = __DIR__.'/hello.txt';

$zip = new ZipArchive();
if (true !== $zip->open($destination, ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE)) {
    die("Problem opening zip $destination");
}
if (!$zip->addFile($fileToZip)) {
    die("Could not add file $fileToZip");
}
echo "numfiles: " . $zip->numFiles . "\n";
echo "status: " . $zip->status . "\n";
$zip->close();
```

The zip gets created, but is empty. Yet no errors are triggered.

What is going wrong?

Comment: The code works - so I'd look at the permissions of the zip file and it's directory.

Comment: Thanks - but the script makes a temporary directory, makes a sub directory puts the file to be zipped into that sub directory, then zips that file from there into a zip in the temporary directory. So I can't fathom why it should have any permission issues since it's having no trouble making the directories or putting files in them?!

Comment: Hmmm... maybe you should post the rest of the script then, since this part is working *(at least on linux). The only other thing I can think of at the moment given the info you've just mentioned is that maybe there's a race condition...

Comment: ziparchive has some major issues in php.  What is the filesize of the created zip? is it a size similar to what you expect? try opening the resultant zip file in notepad++ are the first 2 chars null space ? if they are delete null space then attempt opening zip file again.  are your files there as you would expect ?

Comment: @Dave, it seems that the zip file is of the expected size! But the first two characters are not null. I tried compressing different files and all of them start with: PK[EXT][EOT][DC4][NUL][NUL][NUL][BS][NUL]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It seems on some configuration, PHP fails to get the `localname` properly when adding files to a zip archive and this information must be supplied manually. It is therefore possible that using the second parameter of `addFile()` might solve this issue.

> **ZipArchive::addFile**
>
> Parameters
>
> - filename
>   The path to the file to add.
> - localname
>   If supplied, this is the local name inside the ZIP archive that will override the filename.

[PHP documentation: ZipArchive::addFile](http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.addfile.php)

```
$zip->addFile(
    $fileToZip, 
    basename($fileToZip)
);
```

You may have to adapt the code to get the right tree structure since `basename()` will remove everything from the path apart from the filename.

Comment: This solved it for me! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to give server right permission in folder where they create zip archive. You can create `tmp` folder with write permision `chmod 777 -R tmp/`

Also need to change destination where script try to find `hello.txt` file `$zip->addFile($fileToZip, basename($fileToZip))`

```
<?php

$destination = __DIR__.'/tmp/makeZipTest.zip';
$fileToZip = __DIR__.'/hello.txt';

$zip = new ZipArchive();
if (true !== $zip->open($destination, ZipArchive::OVERWRITE)) {
  die("Problem opening zip $destination");
}
if (!$zip->addFile($fileToZip, basename($fileToZip))) {
  die("Could not add file $fileToZip");
}
echo "numfiles: " . $zip->numFiles . "\n";
echo "status: " . $zip->status . "\n";
$zip->close()
```

Comment: It'd be good to test if the zip file already exists, so then you decide if using ZipArchive::OVERWRITE or ZipArchive::CREATE

Comment: @AedixRhinedale, the documents imply that both `OVERWRITE` and `CREATE` should work whether there's an existing file or not. The difference is simply whether the existing contents of the zip if it exists are replaced or added to.

Answer (score 1):

check this class to add files and sub-directories in a folder to zip file,and also check the folder permissions before running the code,
i.e chmod 777 -R zipdir/

```
HZip::zipDir('/path/to/sourceDir', '/path/to/out.zip'); 

<?php 
class HZip 
{ 

private static function folderToZip($folder, &$zipFile, $exclusiveLength) { 
$handle = opendir($folder); 
while (false !== $f = readdir($handle)) { 
  if ($f != '.' && $f != '..') { 
    $filePath = "$folder/$f"; 
    // Remove prefix from file path before add to zip. 
    $localPath = substr($filePath, $exclusiveLength); 
    if (is_file($filePath)) { 
      $zipFile->addFile($filePath, $localPath); 
    } elseif (is_dir($filePath)) { 
      // Add sub-directory. 
      $zipFile->addEmptyDir($localPath); 
      self::folderToZip($filePath, $zipFile, $exclusiveLength); 
    } 
  } 
} 
closedir($handle); 
} 


public static function zipDir($sourcePath, $outZipPath) 
{ 
$pathInfo = pathInfo($sourcePath); 
$parentPath = $pathInfo['dirname']; 
$dirName = $pathInfo['basename']; 

$z = new ZipArchive(); 
$z->open($outZipPath, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE); 
$z->addEmptyDir($dirName); 
self::folderToZip($sourcePath, $z, strlen("$parentPath/")); 
$z->close(); 
} 
}
```